# How do I fit an image to a bootstrap div="col-md"?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to copy the following picture with bootstrap

[image]
Here's the link if you want to see it https://slack.com/create#teamname
The image does fit the entire page, even though you scroll down , it won't show any extra picture, while mine does have.

My attempt is

```
<body>

<div class="container">

<div id="Page1">
      <h1>Full Name</h1>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <h1></h1>
          <form>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your Full Name" class="form-control">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Show page 2</a>
          </form>
        </div>
      <div class="col-md-7">

        <img src="/img/space.jpg">

      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </body>
```

I add some custom css to the image

```
 img {
    width:100%;
    height:730px;
}
```

and I got the following the result

[image]

How do i match the first picture in code?

I'm not a frontend guy , if anyone could help me would be really helpful.

Here's the JSFIDDLE --> https://jsfiddle.net/3soreoac/

Comment: Please, provide jsfiddle.

Comment: @alirezasafian already added jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/3soreoac/

Answer (score 1):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wKQQxb

```
<div class="left col-md-6"></div>
<div class="right col-md-6"><img class="full" src="https://slack.global.ssl.fastly.net/66f9/img/signup/step1-illi@2x.png"></div>


 .rightfull {
  width: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
}
.left {
  background-color: blue;
}
.right {
  background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: rightfull? and it doesnt work, it is not responsive at all

Answer (score 0):

This may help

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="Page1">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-5 leftpanel">
                 <h1>Full Name</h1>

                <form>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your Full Name" class="form-control"> <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Show page 2</a>

                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-7">
                <img src="https://metrouk2.files.wordpress.com/2014/01/459405755-e1389347715754.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
img{
    width:100%;
    height:732px;
}
.leftpanel{
    background-color:grey;
    height:732px;
}
```

Fiddle:[here](http://jsfiddle.net/fcL3j36t/1/)

Comment: if you look at the site you mentioned,they are using single panel for smaller screens